# Выбор клиента на сервере для взаимодействия по сокетам

Tags: java, сокет

Разбираюсь в **сокетах** в данный момент. Написал клиентскую и серверную части. Все хорошо работает. Вот только один момент. Я совершенно не понимаю, как сделать возможность выбирать, какому именно клиенту слать сообщения с сервера. Неделя гугля результата не дали. Читал про *селекторы*, *компараторы*, *ArrayList*. Ничего не понял. Все без толку.

Comment: Это зависит от того, для каких целей вам надо это понимать. В большинстве случаев сервер посылает ответ тому, от кого пришел запрос. Либо рассылает всем по списку, если это например какой нибудь чат. Уточните вопрос

Comment: Цель такова. Скажем клиент подключается к серверу. Каждому подключению присваивается id. Далее по этому id с каждым отдельно работает администратор. Только рассылка должна осуществляться не всем подряд, а каждому клиенту индивидуально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам просто нужно наделить клиентов идентификаторами. Сделать это можно приблизительно так:

```
TestSocket mySocket = (TestSocket) serverSocket.accept();

public void sendID() {
   DataOutputStreak dos = new DataOutputStream(getOuputStream());
   dos.writeUTF(this.getId());
}

public void receiveID() {
   DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(getInputStream());
   setId(dis.readUTF());
}
```

Comment: Кажется понял. Большое спасибо за ответ. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Не совсем понял. написал все как Вы сказали. Eclipse не видит таких методов, как getId и setId. Не могли бы Вы поподробнее рассказать о них? И getOutputStream, getInputStream разве не к сокету привязывать надо?

Comment: @lemuur вы должны их сами реализовать. Это просто методы, которые возвращают идентификатор(число\гуид итп).

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @lemuur если я дал ответ на ваш вопрос, то нажмите галочку напротив моего ответа, что бы было ясно, что вам  больше не требуется помощь в данном вопросе.

Comment: Сделал. Еще раз большое спасибо)